# Advice on correct structure for using complete sentences in parenthesis

Tags: grammaticality, parentheses

I am trying to include a person's thoughts inside parenthesis. This involves breaking a sentence with other sentences within brackets. Is the following correct structure and grammar or is there a better way please. I am particularly concerned with punctuation and capitalisation preceeding, inside, and after the parenthesis.

In the following text, Taylor is thinking about a word he has just heard - 'murder' to describe a flock of crows. He is trying to remember what that type of word is called -

> Taylor couldn’t help thinking that it was a perfect word (what did they call it . . ? a collective noun) for crows, sometimes they sounded like someone was being murdered.

Comment: I think punctuation like this is more a question of stylistic choice than correctness. You could also separate out the parenthetical phrase between dashes.

Comment: This question might work well on SE Writing.

Comment: Taylor couldn’t help thinking that it was a perfect word (*What did they call it — a collective noun?*) for crows; sometimes they sounded like someone was being murdered.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat - Perfect, looks and reads great - thanks for the insight, I was wary and had been told not to include caps in parenthesis, but it really imparts what I was looking for. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it as correct for me